# Achieve combobox behavior for react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to use the `react-bootstrap-typeahead` control but I'm struck trying to make it do what I want. I've actually got 2 of these on my page, one of which is doing a true async lookup, and one which I almost want to behave like a combobox.

What I'd like to be able to do is to select an item, then click the dropdown to change my mind and choose another item. However if you try this, when you expand the list again it's automatically filtered to just the item you have selected.

For example if I use the basic example on the [demo page](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/), and select `Alabama`, clicking the input now only displays **Alabama** and none of the other choices. I'd like this to ideally return me to the full list (is this possible?).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The `filterBy` prop can take a custom function, allowing you to filter results however you want. So building off the example you linked to, you'd want to do something along these lines:

```
<Typeahead
  filterBy={(option, text) => {
    if (this.state.selected.length) {
      // Display all the options if there's a selection.
      return true;
    }
    // Otherwise filter on some criteria.
    return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  }}
  labelKey="name"
  onChange={(selected) => this.setState({selected})}
  options={options}
  placeholder="Choose a state..."
  selected={this.state.selected}
/>
```

**Update**
As of v3.0.0, the `filterBy` callback passes `props` instead of `text`:

```
(option, props) => {
  if (props.selected.length) {
    // Display all the options if there's a selection.
    return true;
  }
  // Otherwise filter on some criteria.
  return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.text.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: Hi @ericgio,Hope you're doing good, I'm in an urgent serious situation,That I should filter if at least one of  the letter in the option itself includes in the 'search query' ,what should i do,and i dont want to display 'No Matches found'