# Render all options in typeahead menu when item is selected

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using [react-bootstrap-typeahead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead) and I would like all available options to be shown if the input value is an exact match to one of them. I mean if the user writes a value that matches with one of the options I want to display all the options (and make the matched one active) instead of just the one that matches.

I tried using the `renderMenu` prop of Typeahead but I'm unable to achieve the expected behavior. This is my code:

```
render() {
  let options = this.state.options;
  let optionsValues = this.state.options.map(v => v.value);
  let value = this.state.inputValue;
  if ( optionsValues.includes(value) ) {
    const TypeaheadMenuItem = menuItemContainer(MenuItem);
    return (
      <div className="col-4">
        <label className="form-group has-float-label" name={this.props.name}>
          <Typeahead
            labelKey="value"
            onInputChange={this.updateInputValue}
            selected={[this.state.inputValue]}
            options={options}
            placeholder={this.props.name}
            selectHintOnEnter={true}
            disabled={this.props.disabled}
            renderMenu={(results, menuProps) => {
              return (
                <Menu {...menuProps}>
                  {options.map((opt, ind) => 
                    <TypeaheadMenuItem option={opt} key={ind} position={ind} active={opt.value==value}>
                      {opt.value}
                    </TypeaheadMenuItem>
                  )}
                </Menu>
              );
            }}
          />
          <span><b>{this.props.name}</b></span>
          <div className="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I can see the options but for some reason all the options have the prop `active` as `true`.

**Actual Behavior**

Here is a screenshot of how my component behaves right now:
https://gyazo.com/9cbb9842654d681f7ff3e1a2e663e09e

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing mouse re-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184159/allowing-mouse-re-selection)

Comment: Sounds like you basically want a combobox behavior, which is what the question above addresses.

Comment: Can you provide a basic, self-contained repro case? Your code above doesn't work as written.