# How to display all options in react bootstrap typeahead menu with existing selection

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I want the entire menulist to show onFocus instead of only the selected element unlike the pic given below.

[image]

```
<Typeahead
  labelKey="label"
  options={options}
  placeholder="Search.."
  onFocus={(e)=>this.onFocus(e)}
  onKeyDown={()=>this.onChange()}
  ref={(typeahead) => this.typeahead = typeahead}
  selected={this.props.single}
  renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
    <div onClick={(e)=>this.handleClick(e)} value={option.label}>
      {option.label}
    </div> 
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Did you try `typeaheadMinLength` ?

Comment: No is it a prop? Asking this Since i couldnt find enough information regarding this..I can only see the prop minLength using which u can specify how many characters the user must enter before the component will display the filtered results

Comment: It is the same. So give it the value `0`. So that, when the user focuses on the input, the results will get populated.

Comment: I tried it,its not working :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Achieve combobox behavior for react-bootstrap-typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184159/achieve-combobox-behavior-for-react-bootstrap-typeahead)

Comment: When removing defaultInputValue i'm not getting any onChange Event so that unable to update the state. @ericgio

Answer (score 9):

From [similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184159/achieve-combobox-behavior-for-react-bootstrap-typeahead):

> The `filterBy` prop can take a custom function, allowing you to filter results however you want.

Example:

```
<Typeahead
  filterBy={(option, props) => {
    if (props.selected.length) {
      // Display all the options if there's a selection.
      return true;
    }
    // Otherwise filter on some criteria.
    return option.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.text.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  }}
  labelKey="label"
  options={options}
  placeholder="Search.."
  onFocus={(e)=>this.onFocus(e)}
  onKeyDown={()=>this.onChange()}
  ref={(typeahead) => this.typeahead = typeahead}
  selected={this.props.single}
  renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
    <div onClick={(e)=>this.handleClick(e)} value={option.label}>
      {option.label}
    </div> 
  )}
/>
```

**Edit:** The example above assumes that the `options` array passed to the typeahead contains options of type `{ label: string }`. For a different `labelKey` or an array of strings, the filtering would need to be updated accordingly

```
// options: Array<{ name: string }>
return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.text.toLowerCase()) !== -1

// options: Array<string>
return option.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.text.toLowerCase()) !== -1
```

Comment: Where is the `text` variable set in this line?   `return option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) !== -1;`

Comment: @xela84: It's part of `props`, I'll update my answer.

Comment: What is props in the filterBy callback here?

Comment: @Aashiqahmed: `props` represents partial internal state for the component

Answer (score 2):

@ericgio's answer didn't work for me because `react-bootstrap-typeahead` no longer uses the name field.  I used it though to craft my own Typeahead class below with a number of custom options, including showing all options when clicked. It falls back to the original behavior as well when multiple is set to true.

```
import { Typeahead as ReactBootstrapTypeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";
import defaultFilterBy from "react-bootstrap-typeahead/lib/utils/defaultFilterBy";
import React from "react";

/**
 * This class is responsible for setting a few sensible defaults on the typeahead object.
 */
export default class Typeahead extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  /**
   * This shows all of the values when you click into the typeahead, even if something is selected.  See more
   * here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376581/491553
   */
  static showAllOnClick(option, props) {
    if (props.multiple) {
      const newProps = {...props, filterBy: ["label"]};
      return defaultFilterBy(option, newProps);
    } else {

      if (props.selected && props.selected.length) {
        // Display all the options if there's a selection.
        return true;
      }

      // Otherwise filter on some criteria.
      return option.label && option.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(props.text.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <ReactBootstrapTypeahead {...this.props} />;
  }
}

Typeahead.defaultProps = {
  filterBy: Typeahead.showAllOnClick, // Show all of the results even if something is selected
  positionFixed: true, // Display the typeahead above scrollbars
  inputProps: {autocomplete: "off"}, // Turn off autocomplete in Chrome
};
```